# Project builds and runs on debug, doesn't compile on release config

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to create an ipa file from a react-native project. When I build the project using debug configuration, it does it with no errors. It also runs perfectly fine on device and simulator.
The problem is when I change the build configuration to release, it fails with the error shown on the images below.

[image: Example-1]

[image: Example-2]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I had this issue. You have a few options:

1. Upgrade your React Native to the latest version
2. Downgrade your XCode to 9.2
3. Manually patch multiple `NSString stringWithFormat` methods that have the %zd format.

Change every instance of this:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%g|%g|%g|%zd|%@", 
        imageTag, size.width, size.height, scale, resizeMode, responseDate];
```

into this (patch):

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%g|%g|%g|%lld|%@", 
        imageTag, size.width, size.height, scale, (long long)resizeMode, responseDate];
```

[Solution Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18638#issuecomment-377955130)